# WPF Shared DataContext / Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an issue with my binding in WPF currently. I have a two-tabbed application. The first tab contains a datagrid control that is populated by a list. The second tab contains a listbox control that is populated by a list. The problem is if I run the check on the first tab and it returns for example 5 rows in the datagrid, the second tab will populate 5 dummy listbox items. So the controls are evidently sharing the some context, but I'm unsure how to correct that.

XAML for first tab showing binding:

```
<DataGrid Name="WinUpdateDataGrid" Margin="10,79,0,114" ItemsSource="{Binding}" CanUserAddRows="false" AutoGenerateColumns="true" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" ColumnWidth="*" Height="161" Width="509" MaxHeight="150" MaxWidth="700"></DataGrid>
```

Code for first tab showing datacontext:

```
 private void CheckforWindowsUpdates_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckforWindowsUpdates.IsEnabled = false;
        WinUpdateStatusText.Text = "Evaluation in progress...";
        WinUpdateProgressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        WinUpdateProgressBar.IsIndeterminate = true;

        worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

        DataContext = WindowsUpdate.updateClassList;

        worker.DoWork += delegate(object s, DoWorkEventArgs args)
        {
            WindowsUpdate.getCollectionofMissingSecurityUpdates(WindowsUpdate.windowsKBExceptionsList, WindowsUpdate.CabFilePath);
        };

        worker.ProgressChanged += delegate(object s, ProgressChangedEventArgs args)
        {

        };

        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate(object s, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
        {
            CheckforWindowsUpdates.IsEnabled = true;
            WinUpdateStatusText.Text = "Evaluation completed. Missing the following updates:";
            WinUpdateProgressBar.IsIndeterminate = false;
            WinUpdateProgressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;


            if (WindowsUpdate.updateClassList.Count > 0)
            {
                WinUpdateDataGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                DownloadandInstallWinUpdatesButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                WinUpdateDataGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                WinUpdateStatusText.Text = "Evaluation completed. No missing updates.";
            }

        };

        worker.RunWorkerAsync();

    }
```

XAML for second tab:

```
<ListBox Name="ThirdPartyListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="0,70,0,0">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Source="C:\Users\Test\Desktop\Project\ACME-WPF\ACME-WPF\window-new-3.ico" Margin="5" Width="50"/>
                                <Button Name="ThirdPartyInstallButton" Content="Install" Click="InstallThirdPartyUpdatesButton_Click" Margin="5,5,0,0" Height="25"></Button>
                                <Button Name="ThirdPartyPostoneButton" Content="Postpone" Margin="5,5,0,0" Height="25"></Button>
                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Item2.Name}" Margin="12,25,0,0"/>
                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Item2.RequiredVersion}" Margin="3,25,0,0"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item2.CustomUIMessage}" Margin="10,25,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Red"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="You have used " Margin="3,25,0,0"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item3.UsedDeferrals}" Margin="3,25,0,0"/>
                                <TextBlock Text=" of " Margin="3,25,0,0"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item2.MaxDefferals}" Margin="3,25,0,0"/>
                                <TextBlock Text=" deferrals for this update." Margin="3,25,0,0"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

Code for second tab:

```
 private void CheckforThirdPartyUpdatesButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckforThirdPartyUpdatesButton.IsEnabled = false;

        worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

        DataContext = RegScan_ThirdParty.comparisonListWithState;

        worker.DoWork += delegate(object s, DoWorkEventArgs args)
        {
            MainEntry.checkFor3PUpdates();
        };

        worker.ProgressChanged += delegate(object s, ProgressChangedEventArgs args)
        {

        };

        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate(object s, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
        {


            CheckforThirdPartyUpdatesButton.IsEnabled = true;
        };

        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

Full XAML by request:

```
<Window x:Class="ACME_WPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="ACME" Height="411.085" MaxWidth="555.668"
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    WindowStyle="ToolWindow"
    >
<Grid>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="Windows Updates">
            <Grid>
                <Image Name="WindowsUpdateDefaultImage" Source="C:\Users\Test\Desktop\Project\ACME-WPF\ACME-WPF\windowsupdate.png" Margin="0,16,488,286" Width="50"/>
                <TextBlock Name="WinUpdateStatusText" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="267,22,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=WindowsUpdateCompliance, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="14" Foreground="DarkSlateBlue"/>
                <Button Name="CheckforWindowsUpdates" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="54,18,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="207" Content="Check for Windows Security Updates" Height="25" Click="CheckforWindowsUpdates_Click"/>
                <ProgressBar Name="WinUpdateProgressBar" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="18" Margin="54,52,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="207"/>
                <DataGrid Name="WinUpdateDataGrid" Margin="10,79,0,114" ItemsSource="{Binding}" CanUserAddRows="false" AutoGenerateColumns="true" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" ColumnWidth="*" Height="161" Width="509" MaxHeight="150" MaxWidth="700"></DataGrid>
                <Button Name="DownloadandInstallWinUpdatesButton" Content="Download and Install Windows Updates" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,250,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="227" Height="26" Click="DownloadandInstallWinUpdatesButton_Click"/>
                <ProgressBar Name="DownloadandInstallWinUpdatesButtonProgressBar" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="10,286,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="227"/>
                <TextBlock Name="WinUpdateInstallationText" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="256,250,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Third Party Updates">
            <Grid>
                <Button Name="CheckforThirdPartyUpdatesButton" Content="Check for Third Party Updates" Margin="10,11,339,304" Click="CheckforThirdPartyUpdatesButton_Click" MaxWidth="200"/>
                <ListBox Name="ThirdPartyListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="0,70,0,0">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Source="C:\Users\Test\Desktop\Project\ACME-WPF\ACME-WPF\window-new-3.ico" Margin="5" Width="50"/>
                                <Button Name="ThirdPartyInstallButton" Content="Install" Click="InstallThirdPartyUpdatesButton_Click" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=.}" Command="{Binding ElementName=ThirdPartyListBox, Path=DataContext.InstallComponentCommand}" Margin="5,5,0,0" Height="25"></Button>
                                <Button Name="ThirdPartyPostoneButton" Content="Postpone" Margin="5,5,0,0" Height="25"></Button>
                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Item2.Name}" Margin="12,25,0,0"/>
                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Item2.RequiredVersion}" Margin="3,25,0,0"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item2.CustomUIMessage}" Margin="10,25,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Red"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="You have used " Margin="3,25,0,0"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item3.UsedDeferrals}" Margin="3,25,0,0"/>
                                <TextBlock Text=" of " Margin="3,25,0,0"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item2.MaxDefferals}" Margin="3,25,0,0"/>
                                <TextBlock Text=" deferrals for this update." Margin="3,25,0,0"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Information">
            <Grid>
                <Label Name="Info_ComputerNameLabel" Content="Computer Name: " Margin="10,13,397,253" RenderTransformOrigin="0.49,1"/>
                <Label Name="Info_UserNameLabel" Content="User Name: " Width="100" Margin="10,54,419,222"/>
                <Label Name="Info_IPAddressLabel" Content="IP Address: " Width="100" Margin="10,96,419,180"/>
                <TextBlock Name="Info_ComputerNameText" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="137,18,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBlock Name="Info_UserNameText" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="137,59,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBlock Name="Info_IPAddressText" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="137,101,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You don't show the actual binding for WinUpdateDataGrid or hirdPartyListBox.

Comment: The bindings are shown in the XAML snippets.

Comment: ItemsSource="{Binding}" just says the ItemsSource is bound - not what is is bound to.

Comment: Show the entire XAML for first tab and second tab. What is their parent ? Is it in one big XAML file where you define the two tab controls? I wanna see it

Comment: @Blam `{Binding} is equivalent to {Binding Path=.}, which binds to the current source.`

Comment: @lll I did not know that. But might explain why they both have the same source.

Comment: I have added the full XAML for the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that you need to set the DataContext specifically to the Grid and the ListBox. Something like this:

```
WinUpdateDataGrid.DataContext = WindowsUpdate.updateClassList;
```

and

```
ThirdPartyListBox.DataContext = RegScan_ThirdParty.comparisonListWithState;
```

The thing is that if the two functions `CheckforWindowsUpdates_Click` and `CheckforThirdPartyUpdatesButton_Click` is precent in the same codebehind file they will set the same DataContext and the binding `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` in the Grid and the ListBox will inherit the same DataContext.

Comment: That worked, thank you. I just wasn't being explicit enough with my datacontext assignments.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**:`{Binding}` is *not* a shortcut for "binding to itself" (in the sense of [RelativeSource.Self](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource.self.aspx)). Rather, `{Binding}` [is equivalent to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx) `{Binding Path=.}`, which binds to the current source.

---

**To elaborate**: A binding has a *source* and a *path*. You can do a "binding to itself", for example, by using

```
<myUIControl myProperty="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=x}" />
```

This, however, sets the *source* to the control itself, so it will try to access property `x` of the UI control (rather than property `x` of the current data context). From how I understood your question, this is not what you want; in particular, it is not what `{Binding}` does: `{Binding}` keeps the source as it is (usually the `DataContext` of some parent element) and binds to the source itself (equivalent to `Path=.`).

It's possible that your current source for two controls are being shared. I would just explicitly set the `Binding` datasource rather than doing the shortcut method

**Update**:
It is really sharing the DataContext. Can you just create two public properties for those `DataContext` and do the `Binding` from there. Don't forget to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and call the implementation when the properties are being set. That way it is more clear and readable to other developers that there are really two `datacontext` for two different controls.